# Storing a file in cache rather in hard drive due to user's rights

Tags: java, file, caching, user-input, store

I'm wondering if I can store a file in cache (or somewhere else), not on the hard drive using JAVA. I got a file as input, copy it to my hard drive now to an another path, modify the copied one and return with it. But what if a user does not have rights to write on hard disk, so the application which uses the file also don't have? Thats why I'm trying to store the copy somewhere else, for example in the cache, is it possible? If yes, is it also possible without any library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure. It's possible. Why would you need a library? Why do you copy to your hard drive now? How do you do that? How do you modify it? And what do you mean "return with it"?

Comment: Just keep the contents in memory?  If it's too big, how do you plan on trying to find someplace to write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is string file, and small enough to fit into memory you can just use:

```
IOUtils.toString(inputStream, encoding);
```

for binary file you need to reserve byte array big enough to fit the file content into...